# OOP concept understanding

Tags: php, oop

I recently started learning the basics of OOP in PHP.

I am new to a whole lot of concepts.

In the traditional procedural way of doing things, if I had a repetitive task, I wrote a function and called it each time.

Since this seems to be a regular occurence, I created a small library of 5-10 functions, which I included in my procedural projects and used.

In OOP, what is the valid way of using your functions and having them accessible from all objects?

To make things closer to the real world, I created a thumbnail class, that takes an image filename as an argument and can perform some operations on it.

In procedural programming. when I had a function for creating thumbnails, I also had a function to create a random md5 string, check a given folder if said string existed, and repeat if it did, so I could generate a unique name for my thumbnails before saving them.

But if I wanted to generate another unique name for another purpose, say saving a text file, I could call that function again.

So, long story short, what is the valid OOP way to have the method randomise_and_check($filename) (and all other methods in my library) accessible from all the objects in my application?

Comment: Though I can appreciate the reason for your question, the current answers make me want to start a religious nerd war about whether or not `static` methods should be employed. There's a whole debate about dependency injection and static methods just itching to break out. As such, I think your question will likely ***"solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion"*** and is probably better over on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This could not be further from my actual intentions. After all, how am I supposed to know that the answer of my question is debatable, since I am asking and therefore have no idea what the answer is?

Comment: @rdlowrey: Lol! Let the games begin. As you well know, there are 100 ways to skin the proverbial cat, by exposing him to several different options he can select which he feels the most comfortable and git`r`done.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your question. It's just that I don't think there is a universally accepted right answer -- just varying degrees of good or bad answers. It's a *good question,* but it's my opinion that SO isn't the right forum for it. Other people might not agree with me, which is fine too. At this point there are some quality answers so it's pretty useful anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question. The first thing you want to do is identify the primary objects you will be working with. An easy way to do this is to identify all the nouns related to your project. In your example it sounds like you will be working with images and strings, from this we can create two classes which will contain related attributes (functions, member variables, etc). And as you wisely mentioned, we need to ensure that the algorithms you are converting into OOP can be called from any context, so we try to keep them abstract as possible (within reason).

So for your specific situation I would suggest something like:

```
// Good object reference, abstract enough to cover any type of image
//  But specific enough to provide semantic API calls
class Image
{
    // Using your example, but to ensure you follow the DRY principle
    //  (Don't repeat yourself) this method should be broken up into two
    //  separate methods
    public static function randomise_and_check($fileUri)
    {
        // Your code here
        ....

        // Example of call to another class from within this class
        $hash = String::generateHash();
    }    
}

// Very abstract, but allows this class to grow over time, by adding more 
//  string related methods
class String
{
    public static function generateHash()
    {
        return md5(rand());
    }
}

// Calling code example
$imageStats = Image::radomise_and_check($fileUri);
```

There are several other approaches and ideas that can be employed, such as whether or not to instantiate objects, or whether we should create a parent class from which we can extend, but these concepts will become evident over time and with practice. I think the code snippet provided should give you a good idea what you can do to make the jump from procedural to OOP. And, as always, don't forget to read the [docs](https://www.php.net/oop) for more info.

-- Update --

Adding an OOP example:

```
class Image
{
    protected $sourceUri;

    public function setSourceUri($sourceUri)
    {
        $this->sourceUri = $sourceUri;
    }

    public function generateThumb()
    {
        return YourGenerator::resize($this->getSourceUri);
    }
}

$image = new Image();

$image->setSourceUri($imageUri);

$thumbnail = $image->generateThumbnail();
```

Comment: +1 because this is a good answer. That doesn't mean I have to rescind my close vote!

Comment: This is procedural programming , not OOP. Just because you use classes does not mean , that it is object oriented. There isn't even a single object in your code fragment.

Comment: @tereško: Did you read the text, or just the code? There are two objects in the code fragment, String and Image, and both can be instantiated, and extended. Given the examples he posted in the OP I felt that static methods would be a better example, because, imo, there was no need to instantiate an object just to resize an image, or create a hash string.

Answer (score 3):

The way I see it, you have two options:

- Don't worry about cramming yourself into OOP and just make them standard, global functions in some utilities.php file you include wherever you want to use it. This is my preferred method.
- If you take the more OOP approach, you could make them [*static*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) functions ("methods") in some utilities class. From the PHP documentation:

  ```
  <?php
  class Foo {
      public static function aStaticMethod() {
          // ...
      }
  }

  Foo::aStaticMethod();
  $classname = 'Foo';
  $classname::aStaticMethod(); // As of PHP 5.3.0
  ?>
  ```

Comment: It's not that I insist on something, I'm just wondering what is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

Create an (abstract) Util-class with static functions:

**example from my Util class:**

```
abstract Class Util{

   public static function dump($object){
       echo '<pre class=\"dump\">' . print_r($object, true) . '</pre>';
   }

}
```

**How to use:**

```
<?
$object = new Whatever();
//what's in the object?
Util::dump($object);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a beginner, OOP development is not all that different from procedural (once you master the basic concepts it gets quite a bit different, but that's not important to learning the basics).

You deal in OO concepts all the time, you just don't realize it.  When you click on a file in your file manager, and manipulate that file.. you're using Object Oriented concepts.  The file has attributes (size, type, read-only, etc..) and things you can do with it (open, copy, delete).

You just apply those concepts to development by creating objects that have properties and things you can do with it (methods).

In the OOP world, you don't typically make things available to everything else.  OOP is all about "encapsulation", which is limiting access to only that which is needed.  Why would you make a "haircut" method available to an orange juice object?  You wouldn't.  You only make the "haircut" method available to objects that need haircuts.

Comment: I see. So the suggestion is that I add the methods to each object that they have a meaning?

Comment: @AnPel - Not necessarily.  Most functions can be boiled down to working with a single type of object (or types in the case of inheritence).  If a set of code is so generic that it can work with many different kinds of objects, then it's probably a good candidate for it's own type.  In your examples, some of those functions would belong to the Thumbnail object, but others would belong to more generic File objects.  For instance, and md5 routine would belong more with a File than a Thumbnail.

Answer (score 2):

Writing reusable OO software is very difficult.  Even professionals can't get it right a lot of the time.  It requires a mixture of experience, training, practice, and frankly luck in some cases.

You should read about Dependency Injection as it seems to apply to your specific problem.  Basically, you have an object that depends on some abstraction, maybe the "Image Library" functionality.  In your controller, you would create an instance of the "Image Library" object and inject that dependency into whatever other objects required it.

That is, you need to stop thinking on the global scope altogether.  Instead, you have to compartmentalize functionailties in a sane way and tie them together.  Basically, objects should only know about as little as they need to know (also look up Law of Demeter and SOLID).  I reiterate, this is tough to do correctly, and most of the time you can still have an application that works beautifully even if it's done incorrectly.

If you want to be very strict about this you should apply this line of thinking to everything, but if you have a function that wraps something very simple like `return isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] : $default;` I see no real harm in creating a global function for that.  You *could* create an `HttpPost` wrapper class, but that is overkill in most circumstances IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: use ordinary function.  OOP encourages you to think about data and associated routines, using static functions instead of ordinary does not make your program more object-oriented.  Following the single programming paradigm is not practical, combine them when you see that this will make your program cleaner.